# Implementations of BigIntegers with unbounded precision in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, biginteger

I am currently on Java 11, I see that the `BigInteger` has an underlying representation where the number itself is stored in an `int[]`.
Of course to index an `int[]` it is necessary to limit the size of the array by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`,
this is implemented in the source for the current `BigInteger` implementation, if you exceed this value you will get an `ArithmeticException("BigInteger would overflow supported range")` exception.
I do understand that we are talking about really massive numbers here about `(2^32)^(2^32)` (given integers are stored in 4 bytes) give or take the odd sign bit. But in this world of Cloud computing and Micro-services,
I'm sure there are applications out there for calculation with precise integers larger than that value.

Does any one know of any implementations (in Java) for a *ReallyBigInteger* which does not have this limit.

My first thought would be using an underlying representation similar to *RedBlack Trees* (e.g. [Redblack-tree](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/red_black.html#:%7E:text=A%20red%2Dblack%20tree%20is%20a%20binary%20search%20tree%20which,is%20either%20red%20or%20black.&text=If%20a%20node%20is%20red,same%20number%20of%20black%20nodes.))
with the *leaf nodes* holding that portion of the value.

This sort of datastructure should allow the manipulation of numbers bounded only by the computing resource of the owning parties involved.

I'm interested to hear.

Comment: What does cloud computing have to do with big numbers?  Do you just want some sort of unique ID for some purpose, or is there a mathematical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Re Cloud computing: I was more thinking that this would solve/mitigate the issue of not having enough storage/memory on a devise to store such a large value.  
As far as the reason, I was more thinking that mathematical problems would be the more likely use cases, though something may turn up in other cases. For myself it was more interest.

Comment: The only application I have ever seen for the really huge integers that approach the size you are mentioning is for a very narrow sliver of computational number theory research. That sliver is definitely too small for the Java folks to modify the code to support larger integers. Most of these researchers use extremely carefully hand-tuned native code for their work anyway, not Java. That said, it should be possible to have a `ReallyBigInteger` class that used an `int[][]`, in other word an array of arrays of `int[]`, that would expand the size of integers to a max of nearly 2\*\*69 bits.

Comment: It's int[]. So (2^32)^(2^32) or 8GB of memory for a single number. I would consider bigger  numbers as pretty exotic. And the standard library is for the masses. If one needs a bigger number, it's still possible to implement.

Comment: @Sir-RotN sorry, you're correct, question updated. Just interested if there is a 'standard' library which implements such *exotic* numbers.

Comment: It's unlikely, for the reasons mentioned above.  Most of the interesting effort seems to focus on [making the BigInteger library faster](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/17235).

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the link, I'll check it out.